# Math.abs returns wrong value for Integer.Min_VALUE

Tags: java, absolute-value

This code:

```
System.out.println(Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE));
```

Returns `-2147483648`

Should it not return the absolute value as `2147483648` ?

Answer (score 122, accepted):

`Integer.MIN_VALUE` is `-2147483648`, but the highest value a 32 bit integer can contain is `+2147483647`.  Attempting to represent `+2147483648` in a 32 bit int will effectively "roll over" to `-2147483648`.  This is because, when using signed integers, the two's complement binary representations of `+2147483648` and `-2147483648` are identical.  This is not a problem, however, as `+2147483648` is considered out of range.

For a little more reading on this matter, you might want to check out the [Wikipedia article on Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: Well, not a problem is underestimating the impact, it could very well mean problems. Personally I would rather have an exception or a number system that grows dynamically in a higher level language.

Answer (score 50):

The behaviour you point out is indeed, counter-intuitive. However, this behaviour is the one specified by the [javadoc for `Math.abs(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29):

> If the argument is not negative, the argument is returned.
>   If the argument is negative, the negation of the argument is returned.

That is, `Math.abs(int)` should behave like the following Java code:

```
public static int abs(int x){
    if (x >= 0) {
        return x;
    }
    return -x;
}
```

That is, in the negative case, `-x`.

According to the [JLS section 15.15.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.4), the `-x` is equal to `(~x)+1`, where `~` is the bitwise complement operator.

To check whether this sounds right, let's take -1 as example.

The integer value `-1` is can be noted as `0xFFFFFFFF` in hexadecimal in Java (check this out with a `println` or any other method). Taking `-(-1)` thus gives:

```
-(-1) = (~(0xFFFFFFFF)) + 1 = 0x00000000 + 1 = 0x00000001 = 1
```

So, it works.

Let us try now with [`Integer.MIN_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) . Knowing that the lowest integer can be  represented by `0x80000000`, that is, the first bit set to 1 and the 31 remaining bits set to 0, we have:

```
-(Integer.MIN_VALUE) = (~(0x80000000)) + 1 = 0x7FFFFFFF + 1 
                     = 0x80000000 = Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

And this is why `Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` returns `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Also note that `0x7FFFFFFF` is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

That said, how can we avoid problems due to this counter-intuitive return value in the future?

- We could, [as pointed out by @Bombe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444611/math-abs-returns-wrong-value-for-integer-min-value/5444682#5444682), cast our `int`s to `long` before. We, however, must either

  - cast them back into `int`s, which does not work because
    `Integer.MIN_VALUE == (int) Math.abs((long)Integer.MIN_VALUE)`.
  - Or continue with `long`s somehow hoping that we'll never call `Math.abs(long)` with a value equal to `Long.MIN_VALUE`, since we also have `Math.abs(Long.MIN_VALUE) == Long.MIN_VALUE`.
- We can use `BigInteger`s everywhere, because [`BigInteger.abs()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#abs%28%29) does indeed always return a positive value. This is a good alternative, though a bit slower than manipulating raw integer types.
- We can write our own wrapper for `Math.abs(int)`, like this:

```
/**
 * Fail-fast wrapper for {@link Math#abs(int)}
 * @param x
 * @return the absolute value of x
 * @throws ArithmeticException when a negative value would have been returned by {@link Math#abs(int)}
 */
public static int abs(int x) throws ArithmeticException {
    if (x == Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        // fail instead of returning Integer.MAX_VALUE
        // to prevent the occurrence of incorrect results in later computations
        throw new ArithmeticException("Math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)");
    }
    return Math.abs(x);
}
```

- Use a integer bitwise AND to clear the high bit, ensuring that the result is non-negative: `int positive = value & Integer.MAX_VALUE` (essentially overflowing from `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to `0` instead of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`)

As a final note, this problem seems to be known for some time. See for example [this entry about the corresponding findbugs rule](http://findbugs.blogspot.be/2006/09/is-mathabs-broken.html).

Answer (score 14):

Here is what Java doc says for Math.abs() in [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29):

> Note that if the argument is equal to
>   the value of Integer.MIN_VALUE, the
>   most negative representable int value,
>   the result is that same value, which
>   is negative.

Answer (score 8):

To see the result that you are expecting, cast `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `long`:

```
System.out.println(Math.abs((long) Integer.MIN_VALUE));
```

Comment: A possible fix, indeed! However, this does not solve the fact that `Math.abs` is being counterintuitive by returning a negative number: `Math.abs(Long.MIN_VALUE) == Long.MIN_VALUE`

Comment: @bernardpaulus, well, what is it supposed to do, besides throwing an `ArithmeticException`? Also, the behaviour is clearly documented in the API documentation.

Comment: there is no good answer to your question... I just wanted to point out that this behaviour, which is a source of bugs, is not fixed by the use of `Math.abs(long)`. I apologise for my mistake here: I tought that you proposed the use of `Math.abs(long)` as a fix, when you showed it as a simple way to "see the result the asker is expecting". Sorry.

Comment: In Java 15 with the new methods in fact a Exception is thrown.

Answer (score 4):

There is a fix to this in Java 15 will be a method to int and long. They will be present on the classes

```
java.lang.Math and java.lang.StrictMath
```

The methods.

```
public static int absExact(int a)
public static long absExact(long a)
```

If you pass

```
Integer.MIN_VALUE
```

OR

```
Long.MIN_VALUE
```

A Exception is thrown.

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241805

I would like to see if either Long.MIN_VALUE or Integer.MIN_VALUE is passed a positive value would be return and not a exception but.

Answer (score 1):

2147483648 cannot be stored in an integer in java, its binary representation is the same as -2147483648.

Answer (score 0):

But `(int) 2147483648L == -2147483648`  There is one negative number which has no positive equivalent so there is not positive value for it.  You will see the same behaviour with Long.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score -3):

Math.abs doesn't work all the time with big numbers I use this little code logic that I learnt when I was 7 years old!

```
if(Num < 0){
  Num = -(Num);
}
```

Comment: What is `s` here?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to update that from my original code

Comment: So what does this result in if `Num` equals `Integer.MIN_VALUE` before the snippet?