# Why does the negative of Integer.MIN_VALUE give the same value?

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators, ones-complement

Consider the below java code.

```
Integer value = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
System.out.println(value);

value = -value;
System.out.println(value);
```

**Output**

```
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

How the negative value of `Integer.MIN_VALUE` value results the same value? 
However the result can't be `2147483648` because the maximum value of Integer in java is `2147483647`.

But want to know why `-2147483648`? What kind of bit-wise operations are happening internally?

Comment: For the reopen voters, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17256127/438154) answer in the duplicate explains the negation of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Duplicates aren't about the questions being the same, they are about _This question already has an answer here_, as the label states.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What kind of bit-wise operations are happening internally?

Java uses [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation of signed numbers. Therefore, the change of sign operation, consists of two steps:

1. Inverting the bits of the original value, and
2. Adding `1` to the result.

`2147483648`'s representation is shown below:

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

Inverting it produces

```
01111111111111111111111111111111
```

Adding `1` makes it the same number again, i.e.

```
10000000000000000000000000000000
```

due to integer overflow.

Comment: Why do you restrict this to positive numbers as input?

Comment: @laune I see what you mean. Edited to avoid the confusion.

Comment: @Codebender The result of the addition of `1` is greater than what the highest positive value the `int` can hold, so that's an overflow.

Comment: Another nit: Technically, adding 1 to 011...1 does not cause an overflow in the n-bit adder, i.e., the carry flag would not be set in this case. Only the interpretation of the first bit as a sign bit produces the "wrap around" effect.

Comment: @laune It is an overflow in the sense that the [overflow, or "V", flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overflow_flag) would be set as the result.

Comment: I presume that checking the overflow flag is how `Math.negateExact(int)` is intrinsified.

Comment: @the8472 The exact answer to this depends on the hardware, but on most common hardware platforms in use today, the V flag would probably be the answer.

Answer (score 17):

When you negate `-2147483648`, it resolves to `2147483648`, which exceeds the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` with `1`. Then the value overflows to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` again.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html):

> The integral types are byte, short, int, and long, whose values are 8-bit, 16-bit, 32-bit and 64-bit signed two's-complement integers.

So, every unary operation done on an integer will actually be applied on the two's complement representation of the number. 
When the `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is reached it will consist of a leading `0` and 31 `1` bits. Adding `1` would make it a number with a leading `1` and 31 trailing `0`s, which is actually the two's complement representation of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: `When the Integer.MAX_VALUE is reached it will consist of 32 1 bits. Adding 1 would make it 33-bit number with a leading 1 and trailing 0s.` - you got it a bit wrong. Integer.MAX_VALUE is a 0 followed by 31 1 bits. Adding one to it results in 1 followed by 31 0 bits, which is the twos complement representation of Integer.MIN_VALUE