# Kafka's partition choosing algorithm

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

Kafka uses math.abs(key.hashCode) % numPartitions to calculate the partition to send.

What if hashCode is Integer.MIN_VALUE?

As math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE) is a negative number, kafka would send to a negative partition. How is that handled, should I care about this?

Comment: As you said, it use the math.abs() first, so why you worry about this case?

Comment: It's not a bad question: try than in the repl: `math.abs(Integer.MIN_VALUE)` prints: `res0: Int = -2147483648`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444611/math-abs-returns-wrong-value-for-integer-min-value#5444634

Comment: @FredericA. oh, thanks for your share!

Comment: Too bad scala's doc says abs results >= 0

Comment: What is the question about?? it should go to `math.abs(Int.MaxValue) % numPartitions` partition = `2147483647 % numberOfPartitions` but where did you find that code btw I see following code for partitioning `Utils.toPositive(nextValue) % availablePartitions.size()`. where toPositive is `number & 0x7fffffff`

Comment: @prayagupd see the edit

Comment: Sorry it has to be `math.abs(Int.MinValue) % numPartitions = 0th partition` above. And `Int.MinValue & 0x7fffffff` gives you 0, `-1 & 0x7fffffff = 2147483647`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, when I search this in kafka code, It does not use the math.abs() to convert the negative to positive.

It use that:

```
public static int toPositive(int number) {
    return number & 0x7fffffff;
}
```

So It can solve the problem you worried even if the number is 2147483648, it will be converted to 0

> A cheap way to deterministically convert a number to a positive value. When the input is
>         positive, the original value is returned. When the input number is negative, the returned
>        positive value is the original value bit AND against 0x7fffffff which is not its absolutely
>         value.

Comment: really? Which version?

Comment: this is the java kafka client which is also in kafka codebase. You can find in https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/utils/Utils.java. this is not new feature..

Comment: And the defaultPartitioner is in https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/internals/DefaultPartitioner.java

Comment: I was looking into an old version of scala DefaultPartitioner