# Why (-1*-2147483648) gives -2147483648 value instead of 2147483648 in JAVA

Tags: java

-2^31 will give the value -2147483648 but when we multiply or assign n=-n it does not work out, any specific reason in JAVA?

Comment: *does not work out* - what did you mean.  Show us your code.

Comment: Or this? [Math.abs returns wrong value for Integer.Min_VALUE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5444611/7509065)

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  int n=-2147483648;
  System.out.println((-1*-2147483648));
 }

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Understood