# SonarQUBE and compareTo Dates

Tags: java, sonarqube

I got this Sonar Bug:

> Use the original value instead. Rule: Neither "Math.abs" nor negation
> should be used on numbers that could be "MIN_VALUE"

in this method of compare date:

```
public int compareDates(MyDto a, MyDto b) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm");
        try {
            Date dateA = sdf.parse(a.getStartDate() + " " + a.getStartHour());
            Date dateB = sdf.parse(b.getStartDate() + " " + b.getStartHour());
            return - dateA.compareTo(dateB); //Sonar BUG
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            logger.error("Unable to parse date: " + e.getMessage());
            return 0;
        }   
    }
```

I'm using this method to order collections of MyDto by date this way:

> Collections.sort(myDtoList, (a,b) -> compareDates(a,b));

Now I really don't know what to do to amend. The integer given back from the compare can be negative or not, how can i solve to make SQ happy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMO this is almost as false positive.

The result of `dateA.compareTo(dateB)` *could* conceivably be `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in which case `-dateA.compareTo(dateB)` would [*also* evaluate to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5444611/math-abs-returns-wrong-value-for-integer-min-value), thus not producing the result you want.

Realistically that call is *extremely likely* to return either `-1`, `0` or `1` (i.e. it's [*not specified*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html#compareTo(java.util.Date)) to only ever return those values, but all implementations of `Date.compareTo()` that I've seen do that).

**However** there's a very easy way to avoid the negation (and thus this specific issue) entirely:

Just return `dateB.compareTo(dateA)` if you want the opposite direction! Just swapping what you use as the arguments thas the same effect as negating the result, without the risk mentioned by sonar.

Comment: SonarQube seems to fail to recognize `Date.compareTo` returns -1, 0, 1. I wonder whether a local class's compareTo would have the same problem.

Comment: @JoopEggen: the `-1`, `0`, `1` part is just a common convention but it's **not specified**. The docs just say "a value less than `0`". So in theory a conforming `compareTo` implementation could return `Integer.MIN_VALUE` in that case. And that would cause problems exactly in the kind of code OP posted. IMO it's a good idea to be on the safe side in both cases: When *implementing* `compareTo` stick to `-1`, `0` and `1`, and when *calling* `compareTo`, make sure that you can handle *any negative value* being returned, including `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Comment: You are right about the contract of compareTo. An other JDK could do it subtracting.